# How do I check whether an Intent is explicit or implicit?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

Is there a simple way to find out whether an `Intent` is explicit or implicit?

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer with the behaviour recommended in [the Android docs](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction), i.e. that the drawer should open automatically when the app starts, until the user has opened it manually.

However, the activities that use the navigation drawer can be started from a variety of places within my app, as well as outside it. I want to open the drawer only when the activities are launched from outside my app, but I can't find a simple way to find out where an intent came from.

---

There are a few methods in `Intent` that initially looked promising:

- [`getComponent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getComponent%28%29) would seem to give you the information (null/not null) on the sending end (where you already know!) but according to the docs is never null on the receiving end.
- [`hasCategory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasCategory%28java.lang.String%29) could be used to find known categories of external intents such as `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`. This might be what I end up using but I'd rather have a general solution than try to account for each possibility here.
- [`getPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getPackage%28%29) looks like it might do the right thing, but unless I'm not using it correctly it always seems to return null in my tests.

Alternatively, I could always use `putExtra()` to add a flag to all of my internal intents, but that feels too much like a hack so I'd rather avoid it if there's another option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to find out whether an Intent is explicit or implicit?

That's not what you need, given the rest of your question. What you really should be asking is:

> How can I determine internal `Intent` invocations from external ones, with limited hassle?

In that case, for many apps, you can use this algorithm: if `getAction()` is `null`, it's an internal explicit `Intent`. Otherwise, assume it's external.

If, for various reasons, you are using action strings for starting local activities (despite also setting the component on the `Intent` and making it explicit), then you will need to fall back to the "tack on an extra" thing. Normally, if you are starting a local activity with an explicit `Intent`, you are not setting an action string, which makes the action string a clear delineator between implicit (action not `null`) and explicit (action `null`).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is to pass extras with the Intent that identify the Activity that called it, like you mentioned. It's not a hack in particular when you consider that Intents are frequently checked for static identifiers when the Activity finishes and the calling activity checks the result code. Yours is the inverse case of checking the calling Activity.